# Android TextView object are visible before ObjectAnimator starts

Tags: android, textview, objectanimator

I am trying to execute a simple animation using `ObjectAnimator`. Here is the source:

```
TextView[] introTextViews = new TextView[] {(TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView1_1),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView1_2),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView2_1),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView2_2),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView3_1),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView3_2),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView4_1),
                (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro_textView4_2)};

        AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator[] animators = new ObjectAnimator[introTextViews.length];
        for(int i=0; i<introTextViews.length; i++){
            animators[i] = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(introTextViews[i],
                    TextView.TRANSLATION_X, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,
                    0);
        }
        animSet.play(animators[0]).with(animators[1]); // Anim1
        animSet.play(animators[2]).with(animators[3]).after(animators[0]); //Anim2
        animSet.play(animators[4]).with(animators[5]).after(animators[2]); //Anim3
        animSet.play(animators[6]).with(animators[7]).after(animators[4]); //Anim4
        animSet.setDuration(6000);
        animSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animSet.start();
```

The problem is that `TextView` objects are in the screen before animation been started. While Anim1 is running the `TextView`objects that belong to the Anim2, Anim3, Anim4 are on the screen. When Anim2 time has come `TextView` objects dissappear and start the animation, while the Anim3 and Anim4 are still visible waiting for their time to come!
I want the `TextView` objects invisible until they will come in the screen after animation ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this:

```
for(int i=0; i<introTextViews.length; i++){

            //Add this line just to fix the animation initial X point
            introTextViews[i].setX(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels+10);


            animators[i] = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(introTextViews[i],
                    TextView.TRANSLATION_X, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels,
                    0);
        }
```

I know It is a little "hacky" and I am still waiting for any official answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good,and there is another solution you can refer:

in your for loop,set all TextViews to invisible by `setVisibility(View.Gone)`,then set `AnimatorListener` for each Animator,and implement its `onAnimationStart`,where you set the corresponding TextView visible.

Comment: The first thing I tried was that! It didn't work also! When the animation started the method was called but the 3 last animations (Anim2, Anim3, Anim4) were not started actually!

Comment: Do you want other textviews visible when Anim1 is executed.

Comment: No. I want them invisible at the beginning. I want them to be visible after sliding animations have finished